# Convert UTCTime to DateTime

Tags: c++, oracle, datetime, utc

In old c++ source files I have a piece of code, in which an UTC-Time is read.

```
/* current time as UTCTime */
UTCTime = aux_current_UTCTime();
```

I do not know what happens in aux_current_UTCTime! But the result looks something like this:

010228092133 or 110209104849 or 000204091613 etc...

I've tried something like this to read it, but without really meaningful results:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unix_ts_to_date (p_unix_ts IN NUMBER)
   RETURN DATE
IS
   l_date   DATE;
BEGIN
   l_date := DATE '1970-01-01' + p_unix_ts / 60 / 60 / 24;
   RETURN l_date;
END;
/
```

The result ist saved in Oracle as string. How can I convert this information into a meaningful time?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure, but 2 possibilities come to mind:

The string is YYMMDDHHMMSS, so you just need to split it up appropriately (since it was a string). You can find out if any of the dates violate date rules like minutes or seconds > 59, month greater than 12, etc.  You'll also have to figure out what the century should be (e.g. if YY < 70 then century is 20, else century is 19). If none of the converted dates violate the date rules, then I'd guess that's your format.

The string is centiseconds since 1970-01-01 (this seems less likely).

Comment: Thank you but I think, I can't read the data. The old code is: UTCTime * UTCTime = aux_current_UTCTime(); strcpy(TimeStemp, (char*)UTCTime); I dont know, what is the UTCTime type. Probably a C-structure. But when I dont know how it looks, I can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNIX_TS_TO_DATE(P_UNIX_TS IN NUMBER) RETURN DATE IS
  L_DATE DATE;
BEGIN

  SELECT TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') +
     NUMTODSINTERVAL(P_UNIX_TS, 'SECOND')
    INTO L_DATE
    FROM DUAL;
  RETURN L_DATE;
END;
```

That big number looks like the Unix time stamp, which is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch(January 1st, 1970 at UTC).

Comment: I don't think those big numbers are unix epochs: `./epoch2iso8601.py 010228092133  110209104849  000204091613 0 1449685502
2294-02-11 08:42:13
5462-05-22 00:14:09
1976-06-19 21:06:53
1969-12-31 16:00:00
2015-12-09 10:25:02
`

Comment: Thank you, but with your select I get an Oracle error: ORA-01873 "the leading precision of the interval is too small. Cause: The leading precision of the interval is too small to store the specified interval.
Action: Increase the leading precision of the interval or specify an interval with a smaller leading precision".